# Android Studio 0.3.+ Gradle issues

Tags: java, android, facebook, gradle, android-studio

Ever since I updated my Android Studio to its 0.3.0 incarnation, this is the very first time I've created a project in it (previously, all I did was maintenance of already existing projects) and, much to my horror, something seems amiss with either Gradle or importing libs in general.

First of all, gone are all the options to mess around with Project Settings, I understand this is supposedly by design, so I don't break something, but what if Gradle isn't properly detecting the jars in my libs folder? As it stands, doesn't matter what I add there, it's never recognized by Android Studio.

Another issue I'm having is when importing modules, such as the Facebook SDK, I go over to the modules screen and import it and add it to my main module's dependencies.

It all works fine and well in the compiler, with autocomplete working as a clockwork. However, when it's time to build and run the application, the whole thing fails and I get an Error: Gradle: package com.facebook does not exist.

And this even happens if all I do is import the library, not even making any actual use of it (but again, the compiler sees absolutely no issues).

Anyone knows how to fix these errors and what can be done? Importing both jars and modules are of utmost importance for my app and I simply cannot finish it without them.

Comment: I have the same problem with 0.3.1 
I cannot make any progress since Android Studio cannot resolve any dependency.

Comment: @Medo, try to add `repositories { mavenCentral() }` at each `build.gradle`. Gradle needs to know where to look at for your dependencies.

Comment: Same issue here. Since upgrading to Studio 0.3.1, importing gradle projects no longer seems to pull in the dependencies as external libraries. Had to go back to apply idea plugin and gradle idea and open the generated Studio files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much support of visial project editing at the moment, since it is still early alpha version of AndroidStudio. You have to edit your `build.gradle` files manually. The easiest way of create correct gradle builds file is to export them from working eclipse project. (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Particullary for using FacebookSDK i would use next snippet at your application `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven {
       url "http://mente.github.io/facebook-api-android-aar"
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') // this includes all .jar libs
   compile 'com.facebook:facebook-android-sdk:3.5.2@aar' // this downloads facebookSDK 
}
```

Note, that you don't need to checkout facebook sources anymore! Single line dependencies make it so much easier than it was before.

Please, update question with your `build.gradle` if you still have issues. Most likely problem lays there.

Comment: Does this suggested build.gradle setup enable tab completion for dependent libraries? I am having basically the same problem but with junit and the test target.

Comment: Each time you edit `build.gradle` press `Sync Project with Gradle files` or use `auto-import` gradle setting and intelliJ will recreate index and autocomplete will work.

Comment: Thanks, that truly solves the mentioned issues. Could you explain or point me to a tutorial or something of exactly what does what and how? I have couple other modules I'd like to import (mainly local ones).

Comment: After some experimentation, the libs part did not work; this is most probably due to bad placement of the folder itself, but even though I tried moving it around followed by gradle-sync + rebuild, couldn't figure where it's supposed to be located at, could you please tell me?

Comment: Check this wrap up. It has section about jar at libs folder, called "Can I use the support-library.jar?" with project structures. http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/10/common-tips-about-gradle.html