# difficulty creating new Android Library that includes the Facebook SDK in windows

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use the Facebook login tools for my Android app in Android Studio and i have followed all the instructions in [the facebook developers page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dAL6.png)
up until this point [image: Facebook's example]
The problem is this structure is entirely different in windows.This is what i get when i follow instructions 1-3
[image]

Has anyone else done this on Windows before? and how did you get past this problem.

Comment: Check answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831230/import-facebook-sdk-for-android-studio-0-3-1 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598834/android-studio-0-3-gradle-issues

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to open project structure windows :

1. First select your project then press F4 button in your keyboard the appropriate window 
   will be open.
2. Select your project > Right Click > Click - Open module Settings